# Must declare the scalar variable "@dom"

Tags: c#, t-sql, c#-4.0

This is a bit confusing because it worked before and I added 1 little change and I get this error message in my web application. (I do have other cases, I just took out the other cases for simplicity)

Original code that worked before:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRoles]
(@reportid Decimal, @dom varchar(10))

AS
DECLARE @sql varchar(2000) 
SELECT @sql = 
Case @reportid

WHEN 1 THEN
 'select u.id as userId, u.domain, u.isAdmin, u.email, u.canReport, a.[site], a.bldgNum,  a.dataCenterNum, l.shortName, l.[description], a.canApprove, a.canComplete
    from locAdmin a
    inner join location l on  (a.site=l.site and a.bldgNum = l.bldgNum and a.dataCenterNum = l.dataCenterNum)
    right outer join [user] u on u.id=a.userId and u.domain=a.domain
    where u.isAdmin = 1'
End

EXEC (@sql)
```

The only change I did was adding

```
and u.domain = @dom'
```

after where u.isAdmin = 1' at the end so it looks like this

```
where u.isAdmin = 1 and u.domain = @dom'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `@dom` as a parameter when you execute your dynamic SQL.

Replace `EXEC (@sql)` with `exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@dom varchar(10)', @dom` and change `DECLARE @sql varchar(2000)` to `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000)`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Just wondering, but why does the exec command need to change to that and need nvarchar?

Comment: The variable @dom is not in scope in your dynamic SQL. The second parameter to sp_executesql defines the parameters and th following parameters are the values. The parameters to sp_executesql is nvarchar so you had to change that. Have a look [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for more info on dynamic SQL.

Comment: @nhat And of course the most important thing about using sp_executesql with parameters instead of concatenating your SQL string is that it protects you from [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually add the value of the variable to your dynamic SQL:

```
'THE REST OF YOUR QUERY
where u.isAdmin = 1 and u.domain = ''' + @dom + ''''
```

This is because your dynamic SQL is another SQL statement that you are going to execute, and therefore doesn't know about the parameter `@dom` in your original statement.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but I get an error message "Invalid column name 'Yhe'." Yhe is the domain name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need dynamic SQL to to this write this query.

Please do it like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRoles]
(
   @reportid Decimal,
   @dom varchar(10)
)
AS

 select u.id as userId, u.domain, u.isAdmin, u.email, u.canReport, 
        a.[site], a.bldgNum,  a.dataCenterNum, 
        l.shortName, l.[description],
        a.canApprove, a.canComplete
 from locAdmin a
 inner join location l
    on a.site=l.site and a.bldgNum = l.bldgNum and a.dataCenterNum = l.dataCenterNum
 right outer join [user] u 
    on u.id=a.userId and u.domain=a.domain
 where u.isAdmin = 1 and u.domain = @dom and @reportid = 1
```

Comment: I do have other cases, I just took out the other cases for simplicity.

Comment: @nhat - If you can do it without dynamic sql, do so.  dynamic sql is orders of magnitude slower.